# difficulty displaying part of a json response in react

Tags: json, reactjs

so i created a hook to fetch the ISS API. it works fine. but i am having difficulty displaying a specific part of the json that is returned.

[my react fetch hook, the useEffect part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbJa5.png)

my display code
[the code works and displays the first two  tags, but when i add the 3rd  with `location.iss_position.longitude` i get an undefined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3kvA.png)

[the console.dir of the json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlqvV.png)

i have tried many variations of `location.iss_position.longitude` but nothing seems to work and a few google searches were unproductive. maybe my own fault for being able to accurately describe my problem with the correct technical language.

EDIT: heres my full code for fetch and display logic. i followed a tutorial and understand about 80% of it now. still learning

```
export const useFetchPosition = () => {

  // define states for the hook
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)


  useEffect(() => {

    // init loading and error states
    setLoading(true)
    setError(null)

    // fetch api url
    fetch(issUrl)
      // return response as promise with json content
      .then(res => res.json())
      // return json promise, setLoading state, console log
      .then(json => {
        setLoading(false)
        if (json) {
          setLocation(json)
          console.dir(json)
        } else {
          // this else prevents infinite loop
          setLocation([])
        }
      })
      // errors update state here
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err)
        setLoading(false)
      })
    },[])
  // return updated states for export to display
  return { location, loading, error }
}

const Display = () => {
  //call hook and hook data
  const { location, loading, error } = useFetchPosition()

  // loading and error 
  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>{error}</div>

  return (
    <>
    <h2 className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-300 text-center text-6xl">
      {location.message}
    </h2>
    <h2 className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-300 text-center text-3xl">
      response timestamp: {location.timestamp}
    </h2>
    <h2 className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-300 text-center text-3xl">
      current latitude: {JSON.stringify(location) !== '{}' && location.iss_position.latitude}
    </h2>
    <h2 className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-300 text-center text-3xl">
      current longitude: {JSON.stringify(location) !== '{}' && location.iss_position.longitude}
    </h2>
    </>
  )
}
export default Display
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're better off copy/pasting your code into your question. [You can use formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help make it more legible.

Comment: Could you provide your render / return method entirely ?

Comment: @Hurobaki You don't need it. He's already provided enough info

Comment: Actually I need, he’s telling us that he has difficulty to display information. Render method is exactly what I need since he provides his API’s answer which is a not empty object

Comment: @Hurobaki added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

React isn't having difficulty displaying the JSON response; it's having trouble displaying your component before the response comes in, because you are trying to reference members of undefined objects.

Try putting `JSON.stringify(location) !== '{}' && location.iss_position.latitude` instead (presuming your default state, when using `setState` is `{}`)

Alternatively you can define a default state in the same shape as the API's response

## Explanation

This is normal Javascript behaviour.

You've assigned `{}` to `location` when you first called:

```js
// I'm presuming you did something like this
let [location, setLocation] = setState({});
```

At this point, `location` is set to `{}`. You can, in any JS context, try to refer to members of an object that don't exist and you'll get `undefined`.

But when you do `location.iss_position.longitude`, you are trying to reference `longitude` on a member `iss_position` which is `undefined` - this will throw an error. You cannot reference members of `undefined`, but you can reference undefined members on a defined object.

Try running the following in your console:

```js
let foo = {}; // Can't redefine window.location

console.log(foo); // {}
console.log(foo.iss_position); // undefined
console.log(foo.iss_position.longitude); // TypeError: location.iss_position is undefined
```

In fact, your console will tell you exactly that. The error your component is throwing specifically says:

```
location.iss_position is undefined
```

This is telling you that the object you are trying to reference (`location.iss_position`) is undefined at some point (before the API responds, for example)

Comment: when i set it up i had `const [location, setLocation] = useState([])`, i changed it to `useState({})` and added your code and it worked! thanks man. your explanation helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! `useState` takes an initial value, by the way. [Source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L77) and [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable)